# Whenever I highlight an element on my page it will change how it looks and insert bullet points?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Sorry I am new to coding, let me know if I can provide any other details.
I am testing out my HTML and it displays exactly how I want it to. All I am doing is displaying "1H" on a dashboard. However, whenever I am on the dashboard and I highlight the "1H" it will insert bullet points like this " 1 (bullet point) H (bullet point)".
I do not have that anywhere written in the code. I am wondering why it does that whenever it is highlighted?

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example on https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Could you paste the code into your question?

Comment: I doubt it is inserting anything, I am guessing the bullet points are already there but are the same color as the background, so they only become visible when you highlight. But as Iraklis said, we need to see the code and the issue to understand exactly what is going on